# MacBook air shuts down abruptly while using directly with a charger, is it because I am not using battery backup?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

bought a MacBook air in 2018. After a few months, the battery stopped working and I started using it directly with a charger without any battery backup. Sometime later the device started to shut down randomly even when plugged in and especially when using software like Photoshop.

I am anyway planning to replace the battery but before that, I wanted to make sure is this shutdown issue related to battery or something else?

Did anyone face the same issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely to be because the battery is not providing power.

The charger's job isn't to power the computer, it's to charge the battery.
This is significant when the computer wants a lot of power for brief periods. The battery is capable of providing this short burst of full power; the charger is not, so the computer crashes.

Comment: Your bio is lit. Thanks for the information :)